# How to use WAVEHDR

Tags: c, winapi

Where can I find information about what data should be in the `lpData` buffer for the [`WAVEHDR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd743837%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure?

MSDN simply says:

> **lpData**
>
> Pointer to the waveform buffer.

```
typedef struct wavehdr_tag {
    LPSTR               lpData;
    DWORD               dwBufferLength;
    DWORD               dwBytesRecorded;
    DWORD_PTR           dwUser;
    DWORD               dwFlags;
    DWORD               dwLoops;
    struct wavehdr_tag  *lpNext;
    DWORD_PTR           reserved;
} WAVEHDR, *LPWAVEHDR;
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to read up on waveform data. You're expected to know what it is. Use the web to find out.

Comment: I find this all too vague. Why isn't there any decent information about this? I want to know how to generate for example sine waves or play WAV files. Is this function suitable for that?

Comment: There's lots of decent information. What books have you read? What sites have you found on the web. Those MSDN topics are for reference. They do not set out to teach you about wave forms.

Comment: @David: Sorry, I found that there is a chapter 'Generating Sine Waves in Software' in the book *Programming Windows* by Charles Petzold. I'm gonna read that. But how come it is so hard to find information on the web...

Comment: I tihnk Petzold is probably the perfect place to start. I've just had a flick through and it looks like he covers it well. I can certainly see lots of reference to the WAVEHDR structure.

Answer (score 3):

I found this [tutorial](http://planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=4422&lngWId=3) by David Overton very helpful.

Basically, when you call waveOutOpen, you pass in a format structure.  Here's from his code:

```
WAVEFORMATEX wfx; /* look this up in your documentation */
wfx.nSamplesPerSec = 44100; /* sample rate */
wfx.wBitsPerSample = 16; /* sample size */
wfx.nChannels = 2; /* channels*/
```

Then your data in lpData is just 2 bytes per sample (signed short int), left, right, left, etc.

Answer (score 1):

lpData is like an old DOS DMA buffer.
So you can write a piece of track on It like a single block loop.

So in C you declare some proper array ...char myarray[porpersize].
and then you point it ->>>  myhdrstruc.lpData=&myarray[0]

Answer (score 0):

[CCRMA](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/) has a decent overview of the wave file format.

Answer (score 0):

It's vague because the data can be in a variety for formats.  The format is typically specified by a [WAVEFORMATEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757676%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).